# Finding the next number in a text list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list :

```
0000-1001    
0000-1002    
0000-1003    
0000-1004    
2019-0001    
2019-0002    
2019-0003    
2019-0004    
2019-0005    
2020-0012    
2020-0013    
2020-0014    
2020-0015
```

I want an Excel formula that will tell me the next number is 2020-0016

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

Parse the string and add one to the end:

```
=LEFT(A13,5)&TEXT(RIGHT(A13,4)+1,"0000")
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify it as follows to make it work for me:

My list is in the table - Table: Customtbl Column: CustID

First I have to find the last value in the table column:
=INDEX(Customtbl[CustID],COUNTA(Customtbl[CustID]))

Then I used this in your formula above to make it work:
=LEFT(INDEX(tblProjectList[Project ID], COUNTA(Customtbl[CustID])),5) & TEXT(RIGHT(INDEX(tblProjectList[Project ID],COUNTA(tblProjectList[Project ID])),4)+1,"0000")

Answer (score 1):

To find out the `MAX` of the list and assign next number you can use below formula.

`=TEXT(IFERROR(MAX(SUBSTITUTE("0"&A1:A13,"-","")+1),0),"0000-0000")`

Formula shall be committed by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> as it is an ARRAY formula.

Comment: Worked like a charm - As I am using a table I  changed the range to table and column ID:
'=TEXT(IFERROR(MAX(SUBSTITUTE("0"&Customtbl[CustID],"-","")+1),0),"0000-0000")